# Form validation using RegEx for dynamically added controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-plugins

I am using the Jquery Validation Plugin to validate the webform. 
The controls are loaded dynamically depending on the control type. For some controls I need to validate using regular expressions. I need to pass in the RegEx dynamically for each control.
I have the following function but how do I generalise it for all controls that need to be validate using RegEx

```
            $.validator.addMethod(varcharRegEx, function (value, element) {
              return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9\_]+$/i.test(value);
             }, "Invalid entry, must contain only letters, numbers, or underscore.");
```

Second is there a way to show the error messages as a summary at the end of the form.
I am a newbie to Jquery. Please help

Comment: To attach to elements of your choice, just add a selector.

Comment: For different controls I have differenet regular expressions for validation. I need to add the regular expressions dynamically at run time. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom `data` attribute to your controls and populate it with your RegEx. Then you can read that value in the validation function and apply it.

I.e. "decorate" your controls that need validation with some css class, something like:

```
<input id="control_1" class="to-validate" 
     data-regex="^[A-Za-z0-9\_]+$" 
     data-error-message="Invalid entry, must contain only letters, numbers, or underscore." />
```

Then in jQuery attach validators to each:

```
$(".to-validate").each(function(index, myControl) {

    var regex = $(myControl).data("regex");
    var errorMsg = $(myControl).data("error-message");
    var validatorName = $(myControl).attr("id"); 

    $(myControl).validator.addMethod(validatorName, function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || new RegExp(regex).test(value);
    }, errorMsg);
});
```

I have not tested this code, so you might need to adjust it a bit for your exact needs, but I hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: By Validation function do you mean the addMethod of the plugin

Comment: @Floremin What should `myControl` and `index` be ?

Comment: `.each(function(index, myControl)` is basically a `for` loop that goes through an array of all html elements with class `to-validate`. `index` is the current index of the loop and `myControl` is the current html element in the array. Look here for more: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/